# Снятие скриншота с экрана

Tags: java, winapi

Всем привет. Давно уже мучаюсь со снятием скриншота с экрана (либо с окна приложения).

Пробовал через .NET Graphics, а так же через Win api. Недавно начал изучать Java и решил попробовать с помощью встроенного в Java класса Robot.

Результат везде один и тот же - скриншот есть, но он не обновляется.

При попытке снятия скриншота с помощью Win api, снимается один и тот же скриншот в течении работы программы.

При работе с .NET[Graphics] и Java[Robot] снимается так же один и тот же скриншот, но он обновляется при переключении между окнами. Если же окно не переключать, то скриншот всегда будет один и тот же (как при первой попытке).

Может кто нибудь объяснить в чём проблема и как же снимать скриншоты нормально, что бы всегда были разные (то что сейчас происходит на экране или приложении, а не то, что происходило при первой попытке снятия скриншота).

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаю что у тебя не работает, но у меня такой код (в Java) и он работает:

```
public void screenshot(String filename) {
    try {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        String format = "jpg";
        String filenameF = filename + "." + format;

        Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        BufferedImage screenFullImage = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRect);
        ImageIO.write(screenFullImage, format, new File(filenameF));

        System.out.println("Скриншот сохранён!");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }       
}
```

Comment: Сохранение скриншота прекрасно работает. Но сохраняется один и тот же скриншот, хотя в активном окне происходят изменения. Помогает только смена фокуса с активного окна, после чего, своеобразный буффер обновляется, но сразу же зависает и начинает сниматься опять один и тот же скриншот, только тот, что был снят после обновления буффера.

Comment: @МихаилЦарёв я не знаю что у тебя не так, я набросал простую прогу для снятия скриншотов с кнопкой, а слева в фоне открыл просмотр изображений, и каждое нажатие кнопки картинка обновлялась

Comment: Уточню - данная проблема только с полноэкранными приложениями. В частности на OpenGL.